# Converting an SQL result into string format in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to convert the result extracted from the execution of an SQL statement, to a string, as the output is in the tuple format. I am new to Python programming, so, I found a code in the internet that can convert a tuple to a string, but when I tried it out using the tuple gained from the SQL statement execution, the result remains unchanged. Can you please show me how to work it out as intended ? Below is the code that was used:

```
import functools
import operator
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host='localhost',
      user='root',
      password='123456789',
      port='3307',
      database='magna'
)



def convertTuple(tup):
     str1 = functools.reduce(operator.add, (tup))
     return str1


#The converting function

mycusor = mydb.cursor()
mycusor.execute("SELECT Name FROM people WHERE ID =1")
para1 = mycusor.fetchall()


targ = para1
str2 = convertTuple(targ)
print(str2)
```

The result that was produced from the above code :

```
('Mike',)
```

Comment: Can you share example data? Also you are rewriting built-in types (`tuple` and `str`). Use different names to those variables.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @nocibambi , I included them in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

`para1` is a list of tuples.  To convert each tuple to a string we need to convert each element in the tuple to a string, then use [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to combine them into a string.

Using [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

```
joined_str = ', '.join(map(str, tup))
```

or a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
joined_str = ', '.join([str(elem) for elem in tup])
```

If you want to make the entire list into a string, you need to apply another layer of joining

```
joined_str = '\n'.join([', '.join(map(str, tup)) for tup in para1])
```

or

```
joined_str = '\n'.join([', '.join(str(elem) for elem in tup) for tup in para1])
```